# How to mix in two traits when instantiating a case class instance?

Tags: scala

Here goes my REPL session:

```
scala> case class Person(name:String)
defined class Person

scala> trait Hobby{val hobby:String}
defined trait Hobby

scala> trait ProgrammingLanguage{val language:String}
defined trait ProgrammingLanguage

scala> val alex = new Person("Alex") with Hobby{val hobby:String = "fishing"}
alex: Person with Hobby = Person(Alex)


scala> val alex2 = new Person("Alex") with Hobby{val hobby:String = "fishing"} with ProgrammingLanguage{val language:String = "Scala"}
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but 'with' found.
       val alex = new Person("Alex") with Hobby{val hobby:String = "fishing"} with ProgrammingLanguage{val language:String = "Scala"}
```

I don't exactly understand why I can mix one trait but cannot mix two of them in such way. Could you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you are trying to define two bodies for the instance of `Person`. This is not possible. You need to define both `hobby` and `language` in the same body:

```
val alex2 = new Person("Alex") with Hobby with ProgrammingLanguage {
  val hobby:String = "fishing"
  val language:String = "Scala"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I feel like I should have already known this but better learn something later than never.

Comment: "This is not possible." Actually, it is, just not like this: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#early-definitions.

Comment: Interesting comment, thanks. If I understand correctly early definition allows you to embed few more fields but you will not be able to pattern match on them, right?